# Правописание слова "вещмешок"

Tags: орфография, грамматика, словообразование, слитно-дефис

Почему слово "вещмешок" пишется слитно и без мягкого знака после "щ"?

P.S. Можно ли как-нибудь доказать правильность написания слова "вещмешок" через дефис (т. е. "вещь-мешок")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересный вопрос Вы задали. Отвечать буду по порядку.

1. Слово "вещмешок" в первом случае является **сложносокращённым**. Это значит, что его первая часть ("вещ") является сокращением от некоторого слова ("вещевой") и используется, как Вы понимаете, для более краткого изложения мыслей. Такая группа слов практически всегда пишется **слитно**, однако всё же есть некоторые исключения, касающиеся наличия зависимых слов у несокращённого слова. Например:

**Пол красивого мандарина**. (Сравните с "полмандарина") **1**.

Что касается написания, такие сокращения сохраняют **все** свои буквы до некоторой, поэтому мягкий знак появиться не может потому, что в сокращённом слове подразумевается другая буква. Поясню лучше на примере:

Вещ(?)мешок. Основа сокращённой части "вещ" — **вещевой**, поэтому оставляем всё как есть.

2. Да, вполне можно, но значение такого слова будет довольно сомнительным и, скорее всего, ненормативным. Например, можно попытаться объяснить такое написание, скажем, **функциями** данного предмета (вспомните "диван-кровать"), но возникает законный вопрос: а разве мешок не является вещью? Вполне возможно, другие сложносокращённые слова могут быть перестроены таким образом, что оба слова станут самостоятельным и не возникнет смысловых ошибок, но это уже зависит от Вашей фантазии. Во всех же, допустим, тестах, пишите только нормативные варианты.

**Примечание 1**: подобный вопрос, связанный с написанием данной группы слов при наличии зависимых, уже задавался на форуме. Аналогично с морфемой "пол". Хотел бы оставить на них ссылки, но, к сожалению, не могу найти.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Сложносокращенные*** слова, не являющиеся именами собственными, пишутся строчными буквами и **слитно** (Лопатин, § 208
>   http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=95).

В нашем случае *сокращено* словосочетание "**вещевой** мешок" (прилагательное + существительное), означающее *мешок для вещей*. Предложенное же в вопросе дефисное написание сложного слова, составленного из полных слов "вещь" и "мешок", изменило бы его значение - приблизительно на "полувещь, полумешок".

Answer (score 2):

*Вещмешок* пишется по правилу для сложносокращенных слов, которые всегда пишутся **слитно**: вещевой мешок — вещмешок. Мягкий знак там ни к чему, он присутствует только в существительном вещь, но обозначает там женский род, а не мягкость всегда мягкого Щ.

Что такое вещевой мешок? Это мешок для вещей (обычно рюкзак, заплечный мешок). *Вещь — вещевой,* суффикс ОВ является относительным, в данном случае это отношение выражено в том, что в мешок кладут вещи.

А сам рюкзак разве не является вещью? В общем случае да, мешок — это вещь. Из словаря: ВЕЩЬ,  всякий предмет, изделие бытового обихода, личного пользования, трудовой деятельности и т.п. Между словами *вещь и мешок* отношения родо-видовые, их можно записать так: *вещь мешок*. Но никакого смысла эта запись не имеет.

**Дефисное** написание невозможно. Через дефис пишутся сложные слова вида вагон-ресторан, вопросы-ответы, горе-охотник, но там между существительными вполне определенные смысловые отношения.

Answer (score 0):

Вам уже все ответили, я не буду повторяться по сути, хочу только подчеркнуть, что весь ваш вопрос - результат неправильного понимания составляющих. 
Вещмешок - это отюдь не "вещь-мешок", эти он отличается от "плащ-палатки". Это именно "вещевой мешок" - подобно "колхозу" (коллективное хозяйство) или "дурдому".

Отсюда и нормативное написание.